# Error when removing a drawable icon

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to get rid of the drawer [icon](http://www.androidhive.info/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/ic_drawer.png). It's called `ic_drawer` in my project. And when I go to my `MainActivity.java` and remove `R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon`
 I get something that looks like this.

[image]

Here's my full code:

```
    package com.colourity.snatsh;


import com.colourity.snatsh.R;


import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.colourity.snatsh.adapter.NavDrawerListAdapter;
import com.colourity.snatsh.model.NavDrawerItem;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

// nav drawer title
private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

// used to store app title
private CharSequence mTitle;

// slide menu items
private String[] navMenuTitles;
private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mTitle=mDrawerTitle=getTitle();

    // load slide menu items
    navMenuTitles=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

    // nav drawer icons from resources
    navMenuIcons=getResources()
            .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

    mDrawerLayout=(DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

    navDrawerItems=new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

    // adding nav drawer items to array
    // Home
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
    // Find People
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
    // Photos
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
    // Communities, Will add a counter here
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1)));
    // Pages
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
    // What's hot, We  will add a counter here
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1) ));


    // Recycle the typed array
    navMenuIcons.recycle();

    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

    // setting the nav drawer list adapter
    adapter=new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
            navDrawerItems);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

    // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    mDrawerToggle=new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
            R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
            R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
    ) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }


    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    if (savedInstanceState==null) {
        // on first time display view for first nav item
        displayView(0);
    }
}

/**
 * Slide menu item click listener
 * */
private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
        ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        // display view for selected nav drawer item
        displayView(position);
    }
}




/**
 * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
 * */
private void displayView(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment=null;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        fragment=new HomeFragment();
        break;
    case 1:
        fragment=new FindPeopleFragment();
        break;
    case 2:
        fragment=new PhotosFragment();
        break;
    case 3:
        fragment=new CommunityFragment();
        break;
    case 4:
        fragment=new PagesFragment();
        break;
    case 5:
        fragment=new WhatsHotFragment();
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    if (fragment!=null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager=getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    } else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}

@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    mTitle=title;
    getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
}

/**
 * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
 * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
 */

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ActionBarDrawerToggle` constructor is expecting another argument.You are passing only 4 arguments. If you want to get rid of that drawer icon pass a transparent image.

```
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.transparent_image, //transparent image
            R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
            R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
    )
```

Comment: So I should use a transparent image that doesn't show?

Comment: @Anonymous Yes..You can do that

Comment: Nothing changes. I added an image and I get this `transparent_image cannot be resolved or is not a field`

Comment: Did you add that transparent image to drawable folder. Image name should be same.

Comment: Yes. I added it to all the drawable folders

Comment: Oops sorry..It should be `R.drawable.transparent_image`. not R.id.transparent_image

Comment: Check my edited answer..remove `R.drawable.ic_drawer`

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong number of parameters. Provide additional one.
R.id.transparent_image for instance.

Comment: And add an image to my drawables?